# Get browser URL box contents with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I want to make a bookmarklet that will take me to isup.me and check the site that wouldn't load.

So basically it would be like running this in the console:

```
window.location.href = "http://isup.me/" + window.location.host;
```

Which is supposed to navigate me to `http://isup.me/site_I_want_to_check`

This works fine for sites that are *already loaded*, but fails on sites that won't load. Here is `window.location.href` containing the string that is shown in the address bar:
[image]

And here is `window.location.href` on a site that can't be reached:
[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, the value of `window.location.href` does not match what is displayed in the address field. Instead of returning "http://www.minetest.net" I get "data:text/html,chromewebdata" and when I look at the value of `window.location.host` it actually returns a blank string.

**How can I get the *visible contents* of the address bar with JavaScript while viewing Chrome's internal fail webpage informing me that a site cannot be reached?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're on Chrome you can extract the attempted URL from the title element:

```
function url() {
  if(window.location.href=='data:text/html,chromewebdata') {
    return document.title.match(/([^ ]*)/).pop();
  }else{
    return document.location.href;
  }
}
```

Comment: @dandavis I was just being lazy and using that instead of an if statement to detect when you're on an actual webpage - see my edit :)

Comment: This only gives `location.host`, not `location.href`.

Comment: loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl